# expanding two ipywidgets textAreas to the maximum in a HBox container

Tags: python, textarea, ipywidgets

I would like to present two text box areas side by side in an ipywidget as follows:

```
wd_COMPARISON_txt1 = widgets.Textarea(placeholder='text1',
                            disabled=False,
                            layout=Layout(width='auto',height='400px'))
    
wd_COMPARISON_txt2 = widgets.Textarea(placeholder='text2',
                            disabled=False,
                            layout=Layout(width='auto',height='400px'))
```

The way I show that in the dashboard is like this:

```
show_COMPARISON_TEXTAREAS = HBox([wd_COMPARISON_txt1,wd_COMPARISON_txt2])
```

now the result looks like this:

[image]

WHAT I WOULD LIKE IS THAT THOSE TWO FIELDS go all over the tab 50% in width (as show by the two rows in purple), and that the behaviour, if possible, is responsive if I shrink the browser window.

I used 'auto' property in the believed that that will expand the width automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is using the layout of ipywidgets

```
 layout = ipywidgets.layout(width='50%')
```

And pass it to the text area

```
wd_COMPARISON_txt1 = widgets.Textarea(placeholder='text1',
                        disabled=False,
                        layout=Layout(width='50%',height='400px'))
```